# href inside a modal window

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog

basically I have a webpage which triggers a modal containing an HTML form, this form has tabs that you can control with href values, however whenever I click on an anchor link it affects the parent page, but no the modal form.
Normally if the form is not in a modal and is implemented directly on an HTML page the href links work into moving the tabs of the form. However when I make the form into a modal from another page I have this problem.
Any solutions or javascript workarounds? 
Here is the form inside the modal

```
  <div class="tab-content ">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="panel6-1">
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span5"> <h4><i class="icon-user"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp; Property Details</h4>       
  <label>Selected Address : </label>
  <input type="text" value="<?php $result = getAdressFromLatLng($_GET["lat"],$_GET["lng"]); echo $result->address; ?>" class="input-block-level" />
  <label>Property Type </label>
  <select>
  <option id="">Residential</option>
  </select>
  <label>Property Subtype </label>
  <select>
  <option id="">Residential</option>
  </select>
  <label>
  <button type="button" data-toggle="button" class="btn btn-mini custom-checkbox active"><i class="icon-ok"></i></button>
     </label>
     <br />

    //here is the href that when I click on I want to show the panel6-2
     <a href="#panel6-2" ">Go to next tab<i class="icon-chevron-sign-right"></i></a>
      </div>
```

Comment: Solution 1) show us your code

Comment: Done, code added to the original thread.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps setting the target of the href in the modal to the name or id of the modal window?  Otherwise could wrap in modal form in an iframe.